# How to stop Jackson altering datetimes when deserialising them

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to retrieve objects with a date field via a get request to my spring boot app. The dates are correct in the database, correct when debugging, but are altered by 1 hour when jackson deserializes them.

in class

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
private Date matchDate;
```

In application.properties

spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=false

I have no idea why it is altering them, I want jackson to deserialise the dates exactly as they are

Comment: What time zone is your computer using and what time zone is your DB using?

Comment: `Date` doesn't have any timezone info. Hence you might be seeing this issue.

Comment: Let's suppose I tell you I don't believe you. Please don't be offended, and instead, show us an example that we can all try and very clearly proves that I am wrong. That example will obtain and display a date in original format, print it, then get the date in its final format, and print it.

Comment: You're saying that Jackson "deserializes" your objects, but actually it should be *serialising* when reading from database and delivering via HTTP.
Having that said, I don't think that the *adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone* influences the behaviour you see, since it's only for deserialising.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for that setting says,

> "If enabled, contextual TimeZone will essentially override any other
>   TimeZone information; if disabled, it will only be used if value
>   itself does not contain any TimeZone information."

So, since your serialized format does not indicate a time zone, that setting will have no effect on your deserialization.

My suggestion is, if possible, always include a time zone when passing serialized dates around - that way, there is no question about how to interpret the value.